# Instragram redirect URL issue error_message "Invalid scope: []"

Tags: reactjs, redirect, instagram-api, facebook-access-token

I am assuming that the problem with '#' in redirect url so

encode does encode hash so I have used
encodeURIComponent("#")

now '#' become '%23' and url looking like this

[https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=\](https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%5C)<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=https://dev.eventify.io/%23/dashboard/content/social&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code&state=0&eventid=XXX1141927827XXX

BUT I AM GETTING THIS-->

error_type  "OAuthException"

code    400

error_message
"Invalid scope: []"

I am trying to get token from redirect URL and fetch media of logged user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Facing the same problem...